# How do I make `ctr image pull` always use a custom `--hosts-dir` without specifying it in the command line?

Tags: configuration, kubernetes, containers, docker-registry, containerd

I've got a custom file in `/etc/containerd/certs.d/registry.at.my.company/hosts.toml` that has some configuration set up for a local registry container running on my servers. This is working fine when I configure it for a CRI for Kubernetes, but me and my colleagues find it frustrating that we have to add `--hosts-dir /etc/containerd/certs.d` to all our `ctr image pull` commands when running `ctr` manually (outside of K8s stuff.) When we were doing this with docker, it was pretty easy: we just set the right option on the docker daemon's JSON config file (`"insecure-registry": "127.0.0.1"`), and it worked fine. But I'm having trouble finding an equivalent setting for `ctr` to behave similarly. Of course, the CRI plugin is using the `hosts.toml` file I set up just fine, but I would like to be able to manually pull images without having to add an extra flag to the command. Is there a way I can configure containerd so that `ctr image pull` doesn't need `--hosts-dir` passed every time?

Here's what that `hosts.toml` file looks like:

```
server = "http://registry.at.my.company"

[host."http://registry.at.my.company"]
  skip_verify = true
  plain-http = true
```

And in the `/etc/containerd/config.toml` file, I've got CRI pointing to it like so:

```
[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry]
config_path = "/etc/containerd/certs.d"
```

But, as I've surmised and said above, this seems to only affect how the kubelet interacts with containerd, not how `ctr` does.

---

Some background context:

We have this local registry running with an `/etc/hosts` entry like so: `127.0.1.1  registry.at.my.company`. Along with some firewall rules, this makes it so that everyone using our Kubernetes clusters has to push their images to `registry.at.my.company` and configure their pods to use images from there, because our kubelets won't be able to pull from anywhere *but* that domain; and to make it so that our registry isn't a SPoF, we run these local registry containers as read-only mirrors (and the registry container's server itself only accepts local connections, keeping the lack of SSL certs from being a problem.) I am not sure if this is relevant to my problem, but it should help explain why I was talking about the old `insecure-registry` option in docker and why my `hosts.toml` uses `http` instead of `https`, so that it doesn't cause anyone concern.

Also, this is containerd version 1.6.19 that I'm working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, `ctr` cannot be configured to behave the way I want. According to [this discussion on the `containerd` repo](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/discussions/7897#discussioncomment-4574365), you are expected to either create a custom wrapper script or shell alias that will automatically inject `--hosts-dir`, or you should use an alternate `containerd` client which supports configuration in the same way that the `docker` CLI behaved: one such example is [`nerdctl`](https://github.com/containerd/nerdctl).